# Split full name into first and sur name and then combine code to use with the program

Tags: java, arrays, oop, arraylist, split

i'm a first year student and I'm a complete beginner to Java, now i am in trouble with my exercises

Here is part of the CSV file:

```
1,Jay Walker,91 Boland Drive,BAGOTVILLE,NSW,2477
2,Mel Lowe,45 Ocean Drive,MILLERS POINT,NSW,2000
3,Hugh Manatee,32 Edgecliff Road,REDFERN,NSW,2016
4,Elizabeth Turner,93 Webb Road,MOUNT HUTTON,NSW,2290
```

This is my Client class (has constructor):

```java
public class Client {
    private int clientID;
    private String firstName;
    private String surName;
    private String street;
    private String suburb;
    private String state;
    private int postcode;
    
    // constructor
    public Client (int ID, String fName, String sName, String str, String sb, String sta, int pCode) {
        
        clientID = ID;
        firstName = fName;
        surName = sName;
        street = str;
        suburb = sb;
        state = sta;
        postcode = pCode;
    }
```

and this is my code to create object and read data from csv file:

```java
File inFile = new File("clients.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(inFile);
        String str;
        String[] tokens;
        ArrayList<Client> cList = new ArrayList<> ();   
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            
            str = inputFile.nextLine();          
            tokens = str.split(",");             
            
            int clientID = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
            String firstName = tokens[1];
            String surName = tokens[2];
            String street = tokens[3];
            String suburb = tokens[4];
            String state = tokens[5];
            int postcode = Integer.parseInt(tokens[6]); 
            
            Client client = new Client(clientID, firstName, surName, street, suburb, state, postcode);

            cList.add (client);
            System.out.println(client + "\n");
                
        } // end while
```

So i want to print out the result with the format clientID, firstName, surName, street, suburb, state, postcode perpestively. However in the txt file there are just full names and i dont know how to split it into first name and sur name.

And i also could not know how to combine the code to split the name into this program to match

As i run the code above (which i did not split the name), it always wrong and has error :"index 6 out of bound for length 6".

As i must display the result with the format because it is a requirement from the teacher and i could not change first name and sur name into Client Name

Comment: Wow this question looks just like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64493208/use-an-array-or-arraylist-ofan-objects-so-that-all-of-its-records-from-the-file/64493234#64493234

Comment: There are only six comma delimitered fields, if you want to split number 2, then use split.  Plenty of examples on how to split and whitespace

Comment: i can just split the csv file to read it but dont know the code to split the full name, and dont know where to put that code in this program to make it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possible solution (as I can see):

1. write the Client in the file with down comma (,) between the first and sur name, like this:

```
1,Jay,Walker,91 Boland Drive,BAGOTVILLE,NSW,2477
2,Mel,Lowe,45 Ocean Drive,MILLERS POINT,NSW,2000
3,Hugh,Manatee,32 Edgecliff Road,REDFERN,NSW,2016
4,Elizabeth,Turner,93 Webb Road,MOUNT HUTTON,NSW,2290
```

2. split the String from the array again by space, like this:

```
File inFile = new File("clients.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(inFile);
        String str;
        String[] tokens;
        ArrayList<Client> cList = new ArrayList<> ();   
        while (inputFile.hasNext()) {
            
            str = inputFile.nextLine();          
            tokens = str.split(",");             
            
            int clientID = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
            String firstName = tokens[1].split(" ")[0];
            String surName = tokens[1].split(" ")[1];
            String street = tokens[2];
            String suburb = tokens[3];
            String state = tokens[4];
            int postcode = Integer.parseInt(tokens[5]); 
            
            Client client = new Client(clientID, firstName, surName, street, suburb, state, postcode);

            cList.add (client);
            System.out.println(client + "\n");
                
        } // end while
```

Comment: And just hope that Madonna isn't a client ;-)